# Sending multiple POST data items with the same name, using AppEngine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, urlfetch

I try to send POST data to a server using urlfetch in AppEngine. Some of these POST-data items has the same name, but with different values.

```
form_fields = {
   "data": "foo",
   "data": "bar"
}

form_data = urllib.urlencode(form_fields)
result = urlfetch.fetch(url="http://www.foo.com/", payload=form_data, method=urlfetch.POST, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})
```

However, in this example, the server seems to receieve only one item named `data`, with the value `bar`. How could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Modify your `form_fields` dictionary so that fields with the same name are turned into lists, and use the `doseq` argument to `urllib.urlencode`:

```
form_fields = {
   "data": ["foo","bar"]
}

form_data = urllib.urlencode(form_fields, doseq=True)
```

At this point, `form_data` is `'data=foo&data=bar'`, which is what I think you need.

Comment: Thanks Will, this worked perfect (nice and simple explanation)

Answer (score 1):

A normal python dict can't handle this sort of thing; use something like a webob.MultiDict:

```
>>> z = webob.MultiDict([('foo', 'bar'), ('foo', 'baz')])
>>> urllib.urlencode(z)
'foo=bar&foo=baz'
```