# Sending multiple values for one name urllib2

Tags: python, html, request, urllib2

im trying so submit a webpage that has checkboxes and i need up to 10 of these checkboxes checked

the problem is when i try to assign them to one name in a dict it only assigns the last one not all 10

so how can i do this here is the request code:

```
forms = {"_ref_ck": ref,
         "type": "create",
         "selected_items[]": sel_itms[0],
         "selected_items[]": sel_itms[1],
         "selected_items[]": sel_itms[2],
         "selected_items[]": sel_itms[3],
         "selected_items[]": sel_itms[4],
         "selected_items[]": sel_itms[5],
         "selected_items[]": sel_itms[6],
         "selected_items[]": sel_itms[7],
         "selected_items[]": sel_itms[8],
         "selected_items[]": sel_itms[9]

         }
data = urllib.urlencode(forms)
req = urllib2.Request('http://www.neopets.com/island/process_tradingpost.phtml',data)
res = self.opener.open(req)
html =  res.read()
```

this works but i only sends one value for `"selected_itmes[]"` when i look at the actual request in a web debugging proxy it sends multiple values for `"selected_items[]"` but i dont know how to do it with python

please help Thank you!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending multiple POST data items with the same name, using AppEngine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577064/sending-multiple-post-data-items-with-the-same-name-using-appengine)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with `urlencode`; it's that a Python dict can't hold multiple values for the same key. You can see this by `print`ing out `forms` before you send it—there's only one value there for `selected_items[]`. That one value gets encoded just fine.

As [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode) explains, there are two ways around this.

First, you can attach a sequence of values to one key, and use the `doseq=True` flag:

```
forms = {"_ref_ck": ref,
     "type": "create",
     "selected_items[]": sel_itms[:10]
     }
 data = urllib.urlencode(forms, doseq=True)
```

Alternatively, you can pass a sequence of two-element tuples instead of a mapping:

```
forms = (("_ref_ck", ref),
         ("type", "create"),
         ("selected_items[]", sel_itms[0]),
         ("selected_items[]", sel_itms[1]),
         # ...
         )
data = urllib.urlencode(forms)
```

(You can also use a custom `Mapping` type that allows repeated keys, instead of a standard `dict`, but that's probably overkill. Especially since the usual way to construct such a custom `Mapping` type is by passing it a sequence of key-value pairs…)

Comment: Yeah i understood why it wasnt working just didnt know how to get it to work thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating a class and make it return the same string.
In python3:

```
import urllib.parse

class Value(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

params = {Value("selected_items[]"): "one",
Value("selected_items[]"): "two"}

data = urllib.parse.urlencode(params)
print(data)
```

output is:

`selected_items%5B%5D=one&selected_items%5B%5D=two`

Solution was [taken from here](http://www.wellho.net/mouth/3934_Multiple-identical-keys-in-a-Python-dict-yes-you-can-.html)